# REGEX never match for Origin in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, http, litespeed

I have 10 sub domains and getting all static files from a sub domain (static.88n8.com).

I want to allow cross origin for all sub domains in .htaccess with this:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s):\/\/(www\.google.com|google\.com|88n8\.com|second\.88n8\.com|third\.88n8\.com|fourth\.88n8\.com)$" OriginDomainStr=$0
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{OriginDomainStr}e env=OriginDomainStr
```

Or this one:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s):\/\/(www\.google.com|google\.com|88n8\.com|second\.88n8\.com|third\.88n8\.com|fourth\.88n8\.com)$" OriginDomainStr=$0
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{OriginDomainStr}e env=OriginDomainStr
```

Or this one:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s):\/\/(www\.google.com|google\.com|88n8\.com|second\.88n8\.com|third\.88n8\.com|fourth\.88n8\.com)$" OriginDomainStr=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{OriginDomainStr}e env=OriginDomainStr
```

And console showing me:

```
Access to font at 'https://static.88n8.com/font.woff' from origin 'https://88n8.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Which is very weird. That regex should match but seems it doesn't match at all.

I tried this one to check if I can set the header and it worked for main domain:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://88n8.com"
</IfModule>
```

I don't want to use `*` or single domain. Why my regex never match in .htaccess? Seems my [Regex test](https://regex101.com/r/YPHobB/1) is OK.

*Disclaimer: 88n8.com is an example to show my domain is including numbers and English characters in it. It's not my real domain and I don't own that.*

**Edit 1**

As you can see in my REGEX, it should be applied to all `88n8.com` sub domains and google.com (with `https` or `http`).
I have only included 4 sub domains in my REGEX to show you my REGEX.

**Edit 2**

I've added this code to my PHP pages to know current Origin:

```
echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']))? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : 'NOT SET';
```

and the result is `NOT SET`. Seems my `Origin` is empty or NULL and That's the reason REGEX never match.

**Edit 3**

I've checked the server IP with IP2Proxy. This is the Proxy Detection Result:

[image: Proxy Detection Result]

**Edit 4**

I've tried to select anything but still no chance with these two REGEX:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "." OriginDomainStr=$0
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{OriginDomainStr}e env=OriginDomainStr
```

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^(?![\s\S])" OriginDomainStr=$0
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{OriginDomainStr}e env=OriginDomainStr
```

How can I see the value of Origin directly?

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing from `static` subdomain. It's not on the regex of approved subdomains.

Also it won't match http because of `(s)`. To make it optional change `http(s)` to `https?` (it makes the `s` optional). This should also solve everything else because as you're creating a match group with `(s)`, your $0 variable will be `s` and not the domain you wanted.

I'd also suggest combining the subdomains.

`^https?:\/\/((www\.)?google\.com|(first|second|third|fourth|static)\.88n8\.com)$`

All subdomains and main domain from both `88n8.com` and `google.com`

`^https?:\/\/((www\.)?google\.com|(.+\.)?88n8\.com)$`

Comment: Are you behind a proxy that maybe is removing the Origin header?

Comment: Oh, I see there are two groups in the regex. Try changing `http(s)` to `https?`. I'll update the answer as I think this is the case.

Comment: only `.` doesn't set a match group, try `(.*)` instead and see what happens

Comment: Didn't work. I gave up! Will use `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` for font files which is not good to do that. But it's the only option. Thanks for your time.